# How to prevent Bootcamp Windows 10 from 'auto hibernating'

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, hibernate

I installed Bootcamp Windows 10 on a Mid-2012 Non-Retina MacBook Pro. It is pretty good except for one problem. While in Windows, if I close the lid for too long (overnight), it will hibernate itself. I don't want this to happen because it is very annoying that I needs to startup my computer every time it does that. I also don't want to complete disable hibernate with `powercfg /h off` because sometimes I do needs to manually do that. So is there a way to prevent the computer from 'auto hibernating'? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more searching around the internet and playing with the power setting, I found the following steps that can disable it. This works on any computer running Windows 10, not just Bootcamp.

Go to the Control Panel app and go to Hardware and Sound -> Power Options. Now find the power option that you're currently using, then click the Change plan settings button next to that power option. In the windows that appear, click on Change advanced power settings. Now in the small windows find sleep, Hibernate after option (you needs to expand them). Now change both value to 0 and it will turn to never. Finally click Apply to save changes and you're done.

[image: Example]

Note that if you change the power option, you have to do this again for the new power option.